# Project obfuscation along with Native AOT compilation

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, aot, native-aot

I'm developing a small project in C# with .net7 that ends up being compiled into C++ code using AOT compilation. When publishing a project, I would like to obfuscate the C# code and send the obfuscated code for native compilation.
Is it possible to do this and if so, how. Or it would be good to know which direction to move towards achieving this goal.

I tried embedding the obfuscation process in Target MSBuild. In this case, I get the obfuscated C# code, but the generated c++ code remains un-obfuscated.